# Facebook likes and shares not registering on woorank

Tags: html, facebook

I have a problem with a clients website (http://www.luof.co.uk). I am trying to get Facebook likes on the website to link to the Facebook fan page (http://www.facebook.com/londonusedofficefurniture). However, woorank.com says that there are no likes at all? Below is a screenshot of what it shows:

[image: Social Media analysis on woorank]

I have installed Insights, got a likebox, and got a social plug-in at the bottom of the page, yet it still doesn't register. Obviously not relying on Woorank, but linking the Facebook to the website is important for SEO. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Likes and Shares are counted for the URL http://www.luof.co.uk/ and not for http://www.facebook.com/londonusedofficefurniture in woorank.com.

Comment: Yes I know that, but when someone clicks the like button at the bottom of luof.co.uk, it should link to woorank, but it's not?

Comment: U r right, the Shares are registered for the domain http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.luof.co.uk/ Could it have something to do with settings in woorank?

Comment: Right okay, so how do I get it to register? I have tried Insights, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try this plugin for chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrank-seo/mkhilblbmkdnapffblmecglknalglfji/related It shows the count right. The problem seems to be with woorank or its configuration.

Comment: okay thanks! can see the Facebook likes, as long as they are there, then that is good! thanks :)